# QlikSense - Gauge with Range Limits based on a formula

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have some data  (pictured below) that gives the sum of sales for each Canadian province in a table. Clearly from the data Newfoundland has the lowest sales ($102,924) and Ontario has the highest ($3,063,212). I'd like to incorporate this information (these min/max values) into a gauge but I want to use a formula, I don't want to just hardcode the values in case the data changes in the future.

In my load script I let variables vMin and vMax be defined as follows:

```
Let vMax ='Max(ggr(sum(Sales,Province))'; //should correspond to Newfoundland
Let vMin ='Min( aggr(sum(Sales),Province))'; //should correspond to Ontario
```

[image]

[image]

I'm getting some unexpected behavior. It appears that Qlik is calculating this formula based on my selections. In QlikView you can use triggers but I'm using Qliksense Desktop. Is there a way around this in QlikSense Desktop?

Comment: You have misspelled "aggr" in vMax, is that corrected?

Comment: And there is a missing parenthesis.  It should be ='Max(aggr(sum(Sales),Province))';

Answer (score 3):

You can try looking at the whole data set and ignoring what's selected by using `{1}` in your aggregation.

```
Let vMax ='Max(aggr(sum({1} Sales),Province))'; 
Let vMin ='Min(aggr(sum({1} Sales),Province))';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer that worked for me if anyone is interested:

```
Max({1} aggr(sum({1} Sales),Province))
```